# How do I choose page number using python selenium without page number being visible?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to scrape through a webpage. the information I need is back in 2021-2022 so I'd need to move to about page 1000.
My current code starts from page one all the way and doing this till page 2000 or 5000 runs into errors due to internet instability not mention the time it would take because maybe the info i need could be on page 5040.
the x path is '//*[@id="uploadDataTable_paginate"]/span/a[3]' the 'a' index number changes depending on the page number. meaning when it was page 1 it was index 1 when you click pages >3 then it moves to index 3. Although that 'a' class name is 'paginate_button current' that doesn't change no matter the index.

The page number I want isn't visible also so I can't use .click()
this is the image of the page number span
[image: page number image]

Please how do I go about this if it is possible?
I wouldn't even mind if the solution is not in python, I just need to have the idea, I'd figure the python version out.

So basically I made the function to delay and recurse if it runs into exceptions(hoping it is due to network lag) though I am expecting future troubles

```
import os
import sys
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

# increasing python recursion limit so the code could scrape up to 10,000 pages
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

url = 'url'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(5)  # gives an implicit wait for 5 seconds

# set table length from 10 to 100
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uploadDataTable_length"]/label/select'))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("100")

# Get the number of entries shown per page from the drop down box
entries_per_page = int(Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uploadDataTable_length"]/label/select')).first_selected_option.text)

def scrape()
    # while loop for scraping the values I am just hinting
       try:
       except exception: 
               driver.implicitly_wait(5)
               scrape()
scrape()
```